# vulkan-tools fails to initialize on Debian Buster with nvidia graphics card

Tags: debian, nvidia-graphics-card

When I run vulkaninfo I get the error:

```
/build/vulkan-tools-6bmpQy/vulkan-tools-1.1.97+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:3845: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

I am running Debian Buster on a macbook pro, with an NVIDIA graphics card (GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition]).

Any ideas for how to fix vulkan?

Comment: based on this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85107/nvidia-video-card-drivers-for-linux-compatibility

I'm thinking the issue is that I need to install the nvidea driver for my graphics card, from here https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/
instead of the nouveau  driver I am currently using. 

although I haven't yet found something to say Nvidia driver supports my exact model of graphics card, and I'm worried about breaking my system integrity by installing the nvidia driver

Comment: searching for compatibility on nvidia websites yields this driver version:
418.113 https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/153717/en-us

the latest version is 450.80.02 https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/164073/en-us

and the only nvidia driver I've found so far which explicitly lists my graphics card model is: 418.113
https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/153717/en-us

... not sure which I should try using, and hoping there's a way to try to using one which still leaves a way to undo the change if it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that I was using the open-source Nouveau driver for my graphics card (the default on Debian) which does not currently support Vulkan.

By installing the proprietary nvidia graphics driver, the problem was resolved.

I was able to install the nvidia driver by running
`apt install nvidia-driver`,
and then rebooting my computer,
as described in this tutorial https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-on-debian-10-buster-linux

Now vulkaninfo works.